# sort dictionary by key if have same values

Tags: python

I have used sorted function to sort the dictionary by values, I am stuck at to how to sort the dict with keys if they have same values.

This is the final dict I created after sorting values :

```
{'hp': 2, 'technology': 2, 'teacher': 2, 'blodgett': 1, 'mo': 1, 'densetsu': 1, 'stafy': 1}
```

Now how do I achieve it to get i.e., sort keys lexicographical with same values.

```
hp
teacher
technology
blodgett
densetsu
mo
stafy
```

```
for w in sorted(wordFrequencyDict, key=wordFrequencyDict.get, reverse=True):
        print(w, wordFrequencyDict[w])
```

is there any way to sort the dictionary by values in descending order and if values are same then sort is with key lexicographical in ascending.

Comment: instead of `key=wordFrequencyDict.get` use `key=lambda x:(wordFrequencyDict[x],x)` for a tiebreaker